# Should I keep my prompt always open to run the scheduled node.js script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

In a previous question i asked about how to run index.js at an specific time, at first I thought all my project files would go to the web host, but i was told the `index.js` should be run on a server.

I googled and found it. i installed node-schedule, i wrapped my async puppeteer in a function then set schedule.scheduleJob( '44 02 * * *', myFunction) and put my index.html with js/css on a xampp and used ngrok. all right, im very happy my app is live.

now i need to know if i have to leave my prompt live so the scheduler will run always.

i mean, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: yes you should if you use node-schedule.You could use cronjobs if you want to run it only  sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- systemd timers (`.timer` files), a modern version of cron / at
- `cron` jobs (for repeated jobs)
- `at` jobs (for once-off jobs)
- `screen`. SSH into the host, run `screen`, run your command (`node index.js`), press Ctrl D to disconnect. You can then log out of the host and the command keeps running. Log back in and run `screen -r` to reconnect and see the output of the command.